# Consider the sequence $U_{n+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{U_n}$, where $U_0 = 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

1. Show by induction sequence is decreasing.
2. Show by induction $U_n \ge 0$ for all $n \ge 0$

I was able to solve 1. and I am seriously embarrassed that I am unable to solve 2 by induction. I know it is true. I know the sequence converges to 1.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As an aside somewhat removed from the intended spirit of the problem, you’ll find that if you calculate the first few values, you could reasonably conjecture that $U_n=\frac{n+3}{n+2}$ for all $n\ge 0$. You could then prove this by induction and immediately deduce both (1) and (2).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. May be $U_n=\frac{n+2}{n+1}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yep. My eye skipped a line; thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. *"let him who never sin throw the first stone"*. I shall not be this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can prove $U_n \ge 0$ by proving the stronger statement that $U_n \ge 1$. Note that if this is true for some $n \ge 0$, then you have

$$\frac{1}{U_n} \le 1 \implies -\frac{1}{U_n} \ge -1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

so you then also get

$$U_{n+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{U_n} \ge 2 - 1 = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: interesting. I was beating my head senseless with trying to prove it $ \ge 0$. Thanks

Comment: @sku You're welcome. I believe it's a good exercise to show that when using induction with inequalities, you sometimes need to actually use a stronger statement for it to work. Don't feel bad about not being able to directly prove it's $\ge 0$ using induction as I can't see a way to do it either, and I don't think any such way exists.